# Scanning char and Combining Switch statement with If statement? switch(time)

Tags: c, if-statement, char, switch-statement, output

The code that I've wrote:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int yos;
    double salary;
    char time;

    printf("Please enter your employee status, 'P' for Fulltime and 'P' for Parttime: \n");
    scanf_s("%c", &time);
    printf("Please enter your year of service: \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &yos);
    printf("Please enter your current salary: \n");
    scanf_s("%lf", &salary);

    switch (time)
    {
    case 'F':
    case 'f':
        if (yos >= 5)
        {
            salary = (salary*5.0 / 100.0) + salary;
            printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
        }
        else if (yos < 5 )
        {
            salary = (salary*4.0 / 100.0) + salary;
            printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);   
        }
        break;

    case 'P':
    case 'p':
        if (yos >= 5)
        {
            salary = (salary*3.0 / 100.0) + salary;
            printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
        }
        else if (yos < 5 )
        {
            salary = (salary*2.5 / 100.0) + salary;
            printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);       
        }
        break;
    default:
        printf("Please put the details correctly\n");
    }

    return(0);
}
```

for some reason, when I run the program, I get this output:

```
Please enter your employee status, 'P' for Fulltime and 'P' for Parttime:
F
Please enter your year of service:
6
Please enter your current salary:
200
Please put the details correctly
Press any key to continue
```

does this problem occur because it cant scan the char? i even tried spacing the %c. i also dont think that putting %s or %[^\n] will be of any use since its only involve 1 character. please somebody help me?

I've also tried different code which involve only if statements such as:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int yos;
    double salary;
    char time;

    printf("Please enter your employee status, 'P' for Fulltime and 'P' for Parttime: \n");
    scanf_s("%c", &time);
    printf("Please enter your year of service: \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &yos);
    printf("Please enter your current salary: \n");
    scanf_s("%lf", &salary);

    if (char time == 'F' && yos >= 5)
    {
        salary = (salary*5.0 / 100.0) + salary;
        printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
    }

    else if (char time == 'F' && yos < 5)
    {
        salary = (salary*4.0 / 100.0) + salary;
        printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
    }

    if (char time == 'P' && yos >= 5)
    {
        salary = (salary*3.0 / 100.0) + salary;
        printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
    }

    else if (char time == 'P' && yos < 5)
    {
        salary == (salary*2.5 / 100.0) + salary;
        printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

But, this one is giving

```
error c2143 missing ',' before '==' at line 15, 21, 27...
```

there is also this:

```
Warning 11  warning C4553: '==' : operator has no effect; did you intend '='?
```

Comment: `'P' for Fulltime and 'P' for Parttime`....what?

Comment: In second version of your code, it should be `else if (time == 'P' && yos < 5)`  instead of `else if (char time == 'P' && yos < 5)`. Note the extra word `char`.

Comment: You want to read the documentation to `scanf_s()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx ("*Unlike `scanf` [...] scanf_s [...] require[s] the buffer size to be specified for ...*"

Comment: You should decide if your question is about writing C code or Microsoft C code. I each case you should tag your question properly. `scanf_s` is not a C function, but a Microsoft extension.

Answer (score 0):

I opted to use `scanf` instead of `scanf_s`, also I prefer using enums and integers in switch statements. The following edit of your code worked for me;

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int yos;
    double salary;
    char time;

    printf("Please enter your employee status, 'F' for Fulltime and 'P' for Parttime: \n");
    scanf("%c", &time);
    printf("Please enter your year of service: \n");
    scanf("%d", &yos);
    printf("Please enter your current salary: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &salary);

    int status;
    if(time=='F'||time=='f')
        status = 1;
    if(time=='P'||time=='p')
        status = 2;
    switch (status)
    {
    case 1:
        if (yos >= 5)
        {
            salary = (salary*5.0 / 100.0) + salary;
            printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
        }
        else if (yos < 5 )
        {
            salary = (salary*4.0 / 100.0) + salary;
            printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        if (yos >= 5)
        {
            salary = (salary*3.0 / 100.0) + salary;
            printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
        }
        else if (yos < 5 )
        {
            salary = (salary*2.5 / 100.0) + salary;
            printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
        }
        break;
    default:
        printf("Please put the details correctly\n");
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `%c` format specifier, you need to give an additional parameter specifying the number of characters to read.  From the [MSDN page for `scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx):

> Unlike `scanf` and `wscanf`, `scanf_s` and `wscanf_s` require the buffer size
>   to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string
>   control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is
>   passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to
>   the buffer or variable.
>
> ...
>
> In the case of characters, a single character may be read as follows:
>
> ```
> char c;
>
> scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);
> ```

Because you don't pass in the required number of parameters, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So when you read in `time`, do it like this:

```
scanf_s("%c", &time, 1);
```

Also, in your second example, this is invalid syntax:

```
if (char time == 'F' && yos >= 5)
```

Get rid of the `char` keyword here.

Answer (score -1):

`scanf_s` is Microsoft-specific are you use that you must use it? If I try with `scanf` and the [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) compiler then the first version of program seems to work and the default statement is not printed when the program is run.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int yos;
    double salary;
    char time;

    printf("Please enter your employee status, 'F' for Fulltime and 'P' for Parttime: \n");
    scanf("%c", &time);
    printf("Please enter your year of service: \n");
    scanf("%d", &yos);
    printf("Please enter your current salary: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &salary);

    switch (time) {
        case 'F':
        case 'f':
            if (yos >= 5) {
                salary = (salary * 5.0 / 100.0) + salary;
                printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
            }
            else if (yos < 5) {
                salary = (salary * 4.0 / 100.0) + salary;
                printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
            }
            break;

        case 'P':
        case 'p':
            if (yos >= 5) {
                salary = (salary * 3.0 / 100.0) + salary;
                printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
            }
            else if (yos < 5) {
                salary = (salary * 2.5 / 100.0) + salary;
                printf("\nYour new salary is %.2lf", salary);
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("Please put the details correctly\n");
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Test

```
Please enter your employee status, 'F' for Fulltime and 'P' for Parttime: 
F
Please enter your year of service: 
6
Please enter your current salary: 
200

Your new salary is 210.00
```

Comment: ive changed the setting of prepocessor and even tried #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS and even did both. cant really use the scanf for security reason. By the way thanks for the help to all replies